# what is the else statement means in codeigniter index.php line 196

Tags: codeigniter

when the following else statement will be executed?  if the $system_path is invalid, of cause ,it will go to the else statement. however, in this case, the else statement seems to be meaningless.

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/index.php  line 196

```
if (($_temp = realpath($system_path)) !== FALSE)
{
    $system_path = $_temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}
else
{
    // Ensure there's a trailing slash
    $system_path = strtr(
        rtrim($system_path, '/\\'),
        '/\\',
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
    ).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of that `if/else` block is to construct a string that makes any kind of sense for use in the `if` block that follows. That block starts with

```
if( ! is_dir($system_path))
```

If `realpath()` returns FALSE then `$system_path` as written cannot be resolved. But that *might* not mean the path does not exist. Perhaps the developer knows something that 'realpath()' cannot figure out. The `else` part gives the developer the benefit of the doubt. It takes the supplied value of `$system_path` and formats it for use in `is_dir($system_path)`.

Off the top of my head I cannot think of an example where `realpath()` would fail but where `$system_path` does exist. But developers are a creative bunch.

Comment: yes, I know this. But just as I said ,if $system_path does not exist.  the else statement seems to be meaningless.  I guess  It must has some other meaning in this else block code.

Comment: I've revised my answer. Does it help?

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration. I figure out that  when the `$system_path` is written in windows style, for example `$system_path=".\\some_path\\system"`, it is only working in windows environment.  The else statement code `$system_path = strtr(
        rtrim($system_path, '/\\'),
        '/\\',
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
    ).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;` is for solving platform issue.